# What's the difference between HttpClientFactory and Agent?

Tags: python, twisted.web

Before laying my question bare, some context is needed.  I'm trying to issue HTTP `GET` and `POST` requests to a website, with the following caveats:

- Redirects are expected
- Cookies are required
- Requests must pass through a SOCKS proxy (v4a)

Up until now, I've been using `twisted.web.client.Agent` and it's subclasses (e.g. `BrowserLikeRedirectAgent`), but unfortunately it seems as though SOCKS proxies are not supported yet (and `ProxyAgent` is a no-go because this class is for HTTP proxies).

I stumbled upon [twisted-socks](https://github.com/ln5/twisted-socks), which seems to allow me to do what I want, but I noticed that it uses `HttpClientFactory` instead of agent, hence my question:  **what is the difference between `HttpClientFactory` and `Agent` and when should I use each one?**

Below is some example code using twisted-socks.  I have two additional questions:

1. How can I use cookies in this example?  I tried passing a `dict` and a `cookielib.CookieJar` instance to `HttpClientFactory`'s `cookies` kwarg, but this raises an error (something about a string being expected... how on earth do I send cookies as a string?)
2. Can this code be refactored to use `Agent`?  This would be ideal, as I already have a reasonably large codebase that is written with `Agent` in mind.

```

```
import sys
from urlparse import urlparse
from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
from socksclient import SOCKSv4ClientProtocol, SOCKSWrapper
from twisted.web import client

class mything:
    def __init__(self):
        self.npages = 0
        self.timestamps = {}

    def wrappercb(self, proxy):
        print "connected to proxy", proxy

    def clientcb(self, content):
        print "ok, got: %s" % content[:120]
        print "timetamps " + repr(self.timestamps)
        self.npages -= 1
        if self.npages == 0:
            reactor.stop()

    def sockswrapper(self, proxy, url):
        dest = urlparse(url)
        assert dest.port is not None, 'Must specify port number.'
        endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, dest.hostname, dest.port)
        return SOCKSWrapper(reactor, proxy[1], proxy[2], endpoint, self.timestamps)

def main():
    thing = mything()

    # Mandatory first argument is a URL to fetch over Tor (or whatever
    # SOCKS proxy that is running on localhost:9050).
    url = sys.argv[1]
    proxy = (None, 'localhost', 9050, True, None, None)

    f = client.HTTPClientFactory(url)
    f.deferred.addCallback(thing.clientcb)
    sw = thing.sockswrapper(proxy, url)
    d = sw.connect(f)
    d.addCallback(thing.wrappercb)
    thing.npages += 1

    reactor.run()

if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you typically wouldn't use a `HTTPClientFactory`, as it seems it's just a thing that does HTTP requests and not much more. It's pretty low-level.

If you just want to fire a request, there are functions (`twisted.web.client.getPage` and `.downloadPage`) that construct the factory for you, handling both HTTP and HTTPS.

`Agent` is a thing that gives you a higher level abstraction: it keeps a connection pool, handles the HTTP/HTTPS choice based on the url, handles proxies etc. And right, this is the thing you usually want to use.

It seems they they don't share much code and Agent is to `HTTP11ClientProtocol` (and `HTTP11ClientFactory`) as `getPage` is to the old `HTTPClientFactory` (and its protocol, `HTTPPageGetter`). So there's a `twisted.web.client` vs `._newclient` (with the `Agent` as its public API) duality. Historical reasons and backward compatibility, I'd guess.

Anyway, this library won't be nice to mix with `Agent` out of the box, because the API is broken. twisted-socks's `SOCKSWrapper` declares it implements the `IStreamClientEndpoint` interface, but the interface demands the `.connect` method returns a deffered that will fire with an `IProtocol` provider (see [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IStreamClientEndpoint.html#connect)), while `SOCKSWrapper` returns one that fires with the address ([here's the line that does this](https://github.com/ln5/twisted-socks/blob/master/src/socksclient.py#L80)).
It seems you can easily fix it changing the line to:

`self.handshakeDone.callback(self.transport.protocol)`

Once you do that, you should be able to use twisted-socks with `Agent`. Here's an example: (using `inlineCallbacks` and the new `react`, but you could just as well use the standard .addCallback with deferreds and `reactor.run()`)

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.web.client import ProxyAgent, readBody

from socksclient import SOCKSWrapper

@react
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    target = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, 'example.com', 80)
    proxy = SOCKSWrapper(reactor, 'localhost', 9050, target)
    agent = ProxyAgent(proxy)
    request = yield agent.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
    print (yield readBody(request))
```

Also, there's a [txsocksx](https://github.com/habnabit/txsocksx) library that seems to be nicer to use (and is pip-installable!). The API is pretty much the same, however you pass the target endpoint where you would pass the proxy endpoint before:

```
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.web.client import ProxyAgent, readBody

from txsocksx.client import SOCKS5ClientEndpoint

@react
@inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    proxy = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, 'localhost', 9050)
    proxied_endpoint = SOCKS5ClientEndpoint('example.com', 80, proxy)
    agent = ProxyAgent(proxied_endpoint)
    request = yield agent.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
    print (yield readBody(request))
```